# List all sub categories in collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

Building a form for users to submit data. I can't seem to understand or figure out how *collection_select* method works.

Essentially I'm trying to give my users the option to choose which sub_category their product belongs in when submitting the form. What should the collection_select syntax look like?

I ended up figuring it out based on comments, here is what I ended up with, in case it helps anyone else.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:sub_category_id , SubCategory.find(:all), :id , :name) %>
```

Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SubCategory.all
```

instead of

```
Sub_category.all
```

Comment: Thanks Brad..console problem now fixed..I will add edit..Still not sure on the syntax for collection_select for the form.

Comment: There are two approaches, depending on if you are using <%= form_for ...%>   or <%= form_tag %>, edit your question and put in your first stab at how you want your view file containing the form to look.